# Branch prediction numerical integration

Tags: c++, optimization, numeric

Currently I'm writing a program which relies on the Adams-Bashforth equations for numerical integration:

```
void foo::simStep(double dt)
{
    // Prepare integration
    static unsigned long long int curCycle = 0;
    if(curCycle >= 2)
    {
        // Adams-Bashforth 3rd order
        stateArray += dt * (23.0 / 12.0 * statepArray.block<13, 1>(0, 0) -
                             4.0 /  3.0 * statepArray.block<13, 1>(0, 1) +
                             5.0 / 12.0 * statepArray.block<13, 1>(0, 2));
    }
    else if (curCycle == 1)
    {
        // Adams-Bashforth 2nd order
        stateArray += dt * (3.0 / 2.0 * statepArray.block<13, 1>(0, 0) -
                            1.0 / 2.0 * statepArray.block<13, 1>(0, 1));
    } 
    else
    {
        // Adams-Bashforth 1st order (Euler)
        stateArray += dt * statepArray.block<13, 1>(0, 0);
    }
    ++curCycle;
    // Calculate and set the outputs
}
```

This part of the code will be called with 160Hz so the impact of branch misprediction would be very high.

As you can see the 1st and 2nd order equation will be called just once (as long as curCycle does not overflow) and after that it's always the 3rd (first if).

Is there a nicer way to handle such problems? Or does the branch prediciton always do a good job at predicting such "easy" things?

Comment: I assume this is in a function body?

Comment: Correct, with more stuff going on before and after.

Comment: Could `curCycle` ever overflow? Why not to handle the first two steps out of the branching code completely?

Comment: BTW. Usually it's better to embed the small piece of code into the cycle than to call function. And use partial unrolling a couple of times, until the body of the cycle would grow too much.

Comment: AFAIK it should always get it right after the third. It might correctly guess the first, but will probably fudge the second. I'm no expert, though. I just know it favors guessing what happened before.

Comment: Overflow is almost impossible and even if would not cause problems. It's not possible to handle it outside because I want to initialize my class foo and then just call simstep every 0.00625 seconds (160Hz).

Comment: By the way, is `23.0 / 12.0 * statepArray.block<13, 1>(0, 0)` pre-computed by the compiler outside the loop?

Comment: If the values inside `statepArray` don't change, even if they aren't compile time constants, you could store the calculations in an array and use `curCycle` as an index into it. You could remove branching altogether.

Comment: If `simStep` has to be called with constant frequency, why to optimize it at all? 160 Hz is nothing unless `block` function is really complicated (and in the latter case it's easy to use the precomputed values).

Comment: This will be the core part of a dynamic 6DoF modell. When used in an aircraft simulator it should use the least time possible because there are more complicate calculations todo in every cycle like aerodynamics and engine simulation. The statepArray holds the time derivatives of the model (acceleration, velocity, angular acceleration, angular velocities) so they are not constant.

Comment: It depends on *what* branch prediction is being used here. But any reasonable dynamic prediction will eventually predict that it's always going to the `curCycle >= 2` case.

Comment: @MichaGlu If you're using GCC, there are ways to help the compiler: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/branch-prediction-macros-in-gcc/  Not sure about other compilers, or if you should do this at all...